# NiftyNet label_normalization for segmentation

Tags: label, normalization, niftynet

I was using `NiftyNet` to do some segmentation project. For the `Label_normalization` option in `Segmentation` section, in my understanding it's converting the labels into "0,1,...", right? I may be wrong. So my questions are:

1. How does this affect my training process? Is there a difference if my two labels are "0,1" or "0,10"?
2. I saw this label normalization layer only works on label images, so I guess by no means it will affect my inference results once the model is trained. But in fact I got different results with and without `Label_normazation`. Why is that?

I'd appreciate it so much if you could help me with these questions!

Answer (score 0):

The `label_normalisation` layer is an element-wise transformation designed for "ground truth" input volumes of discrete segmentation maps. It's mainly used for computing segmentation losses efficiently during training.

Two possible use cases could be, for example, 1) we can map 5-class segmentation labels of {0,1,2,3,4} into {0,0,1,1,1} and therefore easily create binary segmentation tasks; 2) for a 200-class segmentation problem we can create a sparse matrix to represent a segmentation map (after label normalisation) instead of a memory-consuming binary map with `HxWxDx200` voxels.

But in the first case we couldn't recover the original label space when mapping function used for training is missing. At the moment the output is left in the mapped space at inference time.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! However I have some issues with my case: I guess due to some data type issue, the supposed "1" in `ground truth label` were read as 0.01 by NiftyNet. The generated `histogram.txt` was like `labelfrom 0.01 labelto 1`. So is it gonna be different using `label_normalisation` than not for a two-class segmentation problem? Based on your explanation above, I guess it should be the same, but why did I have different results?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! First of all, if it's '1' in the volume but loaded as '0.01', that's a bug. If you provide a bit more details about replicating the problem here (https://github.com/NifTK/NiftyNet/issues), we'll look into that. And by different results, do you mean different training losses? The losses should be different when the labels are in set {0, 0.01} vs {0, 1} i.e. with/without label_normalisation.

Comment: I guess the bug is not in NiftyNet but in my data management, i.e. when I manually set "1" for label while didn't change other flags in the nifti file. The difference is, if I don't do label normalization, the training loss doesn't drop (dice = ~0.5), but if I do, it drops well.

Comment: I think that's reasonable as the segmentation losses use softmax function by default, the function will force the network outputs to be in the range of [0, 1] and the final outputs always sum to 1. So if the segmentation target is {0,0.01} the loss might not decrease properly.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. That makes sense to me.